# How to use ColorFunction on real data?

Tags: plotting, color, data

I'm trying to use `ColorFunction` on a scatter plot of data ; I would like the point's opacity to go up with the y axis and the level of "Black" on the CMYK color to be a function of the x axis.

However, I don't know how to proceed, as this is real data and not a generated plot. Thanks.

Comment: How are you visualizing the data?  Using a `ListPlot`?  I also don't understand the distinction about real data - you should be able to use the same techniques on real or fake data :-)

Comment: Yes I'm using ListPlot. Haha what I meant was I'm trying to display data instead of functions! Because in the documentation there's a whole lot of examples about using ColorFunction with something like f[x_], but not with actual data points. What you mean Mathematica doesn't know if the data is garbage or not? ;)

Comment: I was just trying to be funny.  See the `listColorPlot` below - you'll have to fiddle around with the color function to get it how you want it.  It should be a pure function that takes 2 arguments, `#1` is the x coordinate and `#2` is the y coordinate.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you are looking to do a `ListPlot` using a `ColorFunction`.  In the absence of the real data, let's use some fake data.

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];
```

It seems to me that this **should** work,

```
ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#1], Hue[#2]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you can see that it doesn't.  That isn't a bug, it's as designed.  `ColorFunction` is only going to be applied to `Line` objects,

```
ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#2], Hue[#1]] &), 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The documentation gives a hint about how to add colors to the points by using `Style`,

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[
  Style[#, Opacity[Last@#], Hue[First@#]] & /@ data]
 ]
```

But you can see that the opacity is ignored, even though that is accepted syntax for `Style` (verify by running `Text[Style["AbBbCc", Blue, Opacity[.2]]]`).

So we are left with creating our own `ListPlot` using `Graphics` primitives

```
Graphics[({Directive[Opacity[Last@#], Hue[First@#]], PointSize[Large],
      Point@#} &) /@ data, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So that works, but it's a pain to use.  We can wrap it up into a function via

```
listColorPlot[data_, colorfunction_: (Hue[#2] &), 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {colors},
  colors = colorfunction @@@ Rescale[data];
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[data,
    {PointSize[0.02],
     Thread[{colors, Point /@ Range[Length@data]}]}],
   opts,
   Frame -> True,
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
  ]
```

Here is an example of how to run it,

```
data = RandomReal[{-10, 20}, {20, 2}];
listColorPlot[data, (Directive[Opacity[#2], Hue[#1]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### edit

A simple way to do this, from Heike's answer in the duplicate, is to simply apply a replacement rule like

```
ListPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#2], Hue[#1]] &), 
  Joined -> True] /. Line -> Point
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]